# __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to take input the person table but I'm getting this error.
I have connect these two models and I'm returning the string to connect it can anyone tell me solution for this below are my codes

this code is from models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    PersonID=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    Lastname=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    Middlename=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    Firstname=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    Initials=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    Title=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    Gender=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    Birthdate=models.DateField(default=None,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.PersonID
    
    


class Function(models.Model):
    FunctionCode=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    FunctionName=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    MinSalary=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    MaxSalary=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    DefaultBillingRate=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.FunctionCode
```

this code is from forms

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Person

class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

this code is from views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Person
from .models import *


def createPerson(request):
    form = Person()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'create_person.html', context )
```

this code is from person.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You have `null=True` on these fields, so you have some instance where these values are `null` and hence `__str__` is returning `None`. Note: Also all of your fields have `null=True`?? Please research a bit on how to design a good database schema (One generally tries to avoid null values)

Comment: can you suggest me  what to write instead of null=true here PersonID=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)

Comment: i got the solution in views form = Person() should be Personform()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see your `FunctionCode` can be null.
your `__str__` method should only return string, but when `FunctionCode` is null it will return `None` instead of `string`.
You can return a non nullable field or you can do this.

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.FunctionCode is not None:
        return self.FunctionCode
    return "Unknown"
```

Comment: I'm getting Unknown sentence on the html page but I want to enter values of personid, lastname, middlename.. over there

Answer (score 1):

If field could be None (null=True), then the `__str__` method can return None. You should prevent this:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.field or ''
```

It returns the field's value if it is not None, otherwise it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

In both models the fields returned by the **str** method can be null, you must establish a condition.

Example:
Model -> Person

```
  def __str__(self):
    if self.PersonID is not None:
      return self.PersonID
    return "Custom String"
```

Model -> Function

```
  def __str__(self):
    if self.FunctionCode is not None:
      return self.FunctionCode
    return "Custom String"
```